# jwilder/nginx-proxy points to the nginx welcome screen

Tags: docker, docker-compose, jwilder-nginx-proxy

I am trying to use the [nginx-proxy](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy) docker container, but if I point to my domain with no subdomain (mydomain.com) then I just get the welcome page. I am using Docker-Compose and my .yml file looks like this:

```
proxy:
  image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
  volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
  environment:
    DEFAULT_HOST: mydomain.com
  ports:
    - "80:80"

frontend:
  image: julienvincent/nginx:react
  ports:
    - "8000:80"
  expose:
     - "80"
  volumes:
     - frontend/src/build:/data/www
  environment:
    VIRTUAL_HOST: www.mydomain.com, mydomain.com
```

Is this an error in my configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is with the `VIRTUAL_HOST` environment variable. When you want to set its value with [multiple domains](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy#multiple-hosts), you MUST not use any space character.

Change it to `VIRTUAL_HOST: www.mydomain.com,mydomain.com` and everything will work out as expected.

Comment: That should really be mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: On this note - going directly to my servers IP now successfully takes me there after this change, however when using my specified domain at port `80`, I still get the welcome screen. Does nginx-proxy support empty subdomain proxies?

Comment: Browser cache issue, empty cache or hit `Ctrl-F5`

Comment: Now I'm just getting `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`. But pinging the same domain responds correctly?

Comment: Nevermind that. Domain is down. I will assume this issue is solved as I can trigger the correct proxy via the direct IP after applying your solution.